# mining alt coins. trading/exchanges

Tags: altcoin, cpu-mining, investing

I am interested in starting to mine alt coins. 
I have little in funds to invest in hardware, besides a laptop that I got from bestbuy. 
are there any coins that would be able to be mined from such a basic setup?

my goal is to get coins and then trade them in for bitcoins and then onto fiat.

im not looking for a big return in profits at first just something to get me started and then to work my way up?

if there us anything you would like clarified please let me know

Comment: Regardless of the coin you choose, I think it's very unlikely you'll be able to make any significant profits mining with one off-the-shelf laptop.  Pennies, if you're lucky.

Comment: also see: [Why does mining profitability tend towards zero?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2154/5406)