# is there a new coin in the market that can be mined using CPU only?

Tags: mining-reward

what is the coin name that I should mine using my persona PC CPU to make any kind of money.
my expectation is that it will be a coin designed to be mined using CPU mainly and in the same time, has a strong demand, so its value will not be dragged to zero fast like many other coins.
I realize that the question have been asked before in 2013 but I'm sure the answer should be different today.
thanks for any feedback.

Comment: related: [Why does mining profitability tend towards zero?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2154/5406)

Comment: Standard economics suggests this is unlikely. If there were a valuable coin that was easy to mine, you'd expect that many other people would already be doing it. This would very quickly either drive up the difficulty (so that it's no longer easy to mine) or flood the market with coins (so that they're no longer valuable).

Answer (score 2):

I sincerely doubt that there is such a thing: If there were a coin with high demand, more people would mine it and mining would get more competitive. Making a coin CPU minable only, allows botnets to dominate mining, hence making mining more competitive. In general whenever mining is profitable, it will become more competitive until it is only for those at an advantage. – There is no such thing as a free lunch.

There might be some obscure altcoins that can be mined profitably, but as any of them may go bust over night, and profitability keeps shifting from one to the other, you'll spend as much time reading, reconfiguring and trading that it'll be unprofitable concerning your time-investment.

You'll probably be able to pick two out of three at most: low risk, high profitabity, low time-investment.

But hey, that's just why I think it's not worth looking into, I might be wrong.