# I'm not able to mine as much Bitcoin as I was able to a couple of months ago

Tags: difficulty, mining-profitability, antminer

I’ve been using two `AntMiner S5 ~1155Gh/s` and was able to mine about 0.02 Bitcoin.
 However, recently I’m just able to about 0.01 Bitcoin.

I use F2Pool for mining. I thought first the other one isn’t working but it does.
Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: possible duplicate: [Why does mining profitability tend towards zero?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2154/5406)

Answer (score 3):

As more people contribute to mining, Bitcoin automatically adjusts the ["difficulty"](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty) so that the number of new bitcoins created by mining is roughly the same over time. The [difficulty has increased rapidly in the last few months](https://bitcoinwisdom.com/bitcoin/difficulty), and in fact it has nearly doubled since November 2015. This matches with your performance numbers. Your existing hardware will become less useful over time.